# EntityFramework StackOverflowException calling Dbset.Attach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stack-overflow

We are hitting a StackOverflowException when using EntityFramework in production, but not in our testing suite. When we increase the stack size from 1MB to 50MB, the stack overflow disappears, but we have a very simple set of tables. I suspect this is something simple we can solve by configuring our EntityFramework relationships in a slightly different manner.

Basically, we are deleting a single item from the database, but the data set is too big to fit into memory (100k+ items, several GB on disk). We read that the best method is to attach the object first, then delete it, then save.

This results in a stack overflow like this

```
(many more similar lines snipped)
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 1823    C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<ObjectIdentifier>.Include(bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 346 C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 2308    C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool relationshipAlreadyExists, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 1588     C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 1823    C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<TrackedObject>.Include(bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 471 C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 2308    C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool relationshipAlreadyExists, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 1588     C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 1823    C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference<ShippedUpdate>.Include(bool addRelationshipAsUnchanged, bool doAttach) Line 346 C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(bool doAttach) Line 1255        C#
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(string entitySetName, object entity) Line 1261               C#
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TrackedObject>.Attach.AnonymousMethod__9() Line 339                C#
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TrackedObject>.ActOnSet(System.Action action, System.Data.Entity.EntityState newState, object entity, string methodName) Line 449    C#
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet<TrackedObject>.Attach(object entity) Line 338 C#
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TrackedObject>.Attach(TrackedObject entity) Line 154 C#
```

EntityFramework seems to be traversing a huge number of nested relationships unnecessarily - I'm not sure why attaching a single object would cause such a large amount of work? All we need to do is add/delete a row from a SQL Server table then either update any in-memory lists or cascade delete the dependent objects.

Is it perhaps to do with the way my relationships are defined in our code-first classes? Can I put an attribute on the relationships to say "ignore this when attaching"?

Some code for our classes: (snipped a lot)

```
public class TrackedObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Identity { get; set; }

    public ObjectIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IdentifierIdentity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ShippedUpdateIdentity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TrackedObjectIdentity")]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackedObjectDependency> TrackedObjectDependencies { get; set; }

    public virtual ShippedUpdate ShippedUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectIdentifier : IEquatable<ObjectIdentifier>
{        
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Identity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdentifierIdentity")]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackedObject> TrackedObjects { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdentifierIdentity")]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackedObjectDependency> TrackedObjectDependencies { get; set; }
}

public class ShippedUpdate
{        
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Identity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShippedUpdateIdentity")]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackedObject> TrackedObjects { get; set; }
}

public class TrackedObjectDependency
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Identity { get; set; }

    public ObjectIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IdentifierIdentity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TrackedObjectIdentity { get; set; }

    public TrackedObject TrackedObject { get; set; }
}
```

The code to delete items is fairly simple:

```
dbContext.TrackedObjects.Attach(trackedItemToDelete);
dbContext.TrackedObjects.Remove(trackedItemToDelete);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But this is causing a `StackOverflowException`.
Is this purely a schema definition issue? Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering (not an answer though), may it be possible that the `TrackedObject` has itself on a `TrackedObjectDependency` and it might just be producing some infinite loop? (that wouldn't explain why increasing the stack prevents this, but just out of curiosity)

Comment: Yes, ObjectIdentifier has a list of TrackedObjectDependency which itself has an ObjectIdentifier. So something about this recursive relationship is preventing me from adding a node to this graph. The question is - how to prevent EF from fully populating the entire graph when I attach a new object to it?

Comment: If the object is detached, and it's not a proxy... well, this is just a big wild shoot in the air, totally untested and just out of my mind... but you could try setting the virtual collections to `null` on the object before attaching it, and to EF, it *should* look as an object whose relationships have never been loaded (`Attach` should not try to load them in this case). Again, this is some weird, risky operation and you might have to look for possible side-effects... but it's worth a try

Comment: Then again, you should load the relationship later if you plan to cascade delete when calling `Remove` (if you don't, it shouldn't be needed), but this could at least prove if it's a bug/feature/limit of `Attach`

Comment: To clarify - you're suggesting that it's the relationships on the object i'm attaching that have the too-large tree, rather than the objects already in the database that I'm attaching to, right? So for example looking at the stack trace it's TrackedObject -> ShippedUpdate -> TrackedObject -> ObjectIdentifier... so perhaps I can trim off the ShippedUpdate?

Comment: Yep. That, or a problem in the EF's Attach method. Going from "being able to attach and delete", I guess you could test at what point it begins to fail (by adding collections one by one) and diagnose based on the data.